# What's the best space to capture an Anee

Tags: monster-galaxy-the-zodiac-islands

In the game "Monster Galaxy: The Zodiac Islands", I know that Anees appear on the island of Cancer, and I once even fought one there, but I messed up and killed it by accident, and haven't seen one since. I need to find another so I can catch it, to complete my set.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After more digging, I found this awesome site which lists the location where every Moga can be captured. The Anee (only found at Albus Ruinea) is now in my stable... on to the next.

http://monstergalaxydatabase.blogspot.com/2011/09/zodiac-islands-moga-list.html?m=1